# Retrieving values crossing arrays gives unlogic result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In Drupal context, while printing checked exposed filters in a somehow standard code snippet, I can't print more than one value, and I can't find the missing logic of my foreach loop :

```
<?php 
foreach ($exposed_filters as $filter => $value) { 

  if ($filter == 'foo') {
    $field = field_info_field('field_foo');
    $allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field); 
    //returns an array with 14 string values & numeric keys 
    //e.g array(0=>'bla', 1=>'bar', 2=>'xx', 3=>'yy')

    $h = explode(',', $value);//returns checked ids of foo filter e.g array(0 => 2, 1=>3)
    $exp_heb = '';
    foreach ($h as $k=>$v) {
      $exp_heb .= $allowed_values[$v] . ', ';
    }
    $exp_heb = substr($exp_heb, 0, -2);
    print $exp_heb;
  }
}
?>
```

Should return : *xx, yy* but I get xx,,

I checked step by step printing out my arrays, values... everything's looks fine but result is wrong. Do I need a rest ???

This is `dpm($allowed_values)` output

[image: allowed values]

Comment: 3x `{` ; 2x `}` *hmmm*

Comment: @Rizier123 tks, not that code error, just forgot a } when copying to stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I have to get the integer value of my variable, before passing it as a key :

```
foreach ($h as $k=>$v) {
  $exp_heb .= $allowed_values[intval($v)] . ', ';
}
```

For a reason **I would be glad to be taught**, even if it's always an id, and prints out a number, first time it's passed as integer, but then not.

Answer (score 0):

May be this line cuts your output?

```
$exp_heb = substr($exp_heb, 0, -2);
```

Comment: Tks. No it just cuts last `,` and a space. When I became crazy I commented it off anyway, with no change of course. Any other idea ? ;-)

Comment: Ok. By the way, I think rtrim($string, ",") looks more precise here). Let me think...

Comment: Can you vardump  $exp_heb right after inner foreach? I want to see the value of this variable

Comment: Sorry I've been at phone : `string(20) "Gîte d’étape, , " `

Comment: Looks like it's a completely different value from what you're expecting?

Comment: Can you show vardumps of $exposed_filters and $allowed_values in your answer above?

Comment: yes, if I check 2 values, I must get 2 strings, as in the question example. I added `$allowed_values` in question (drupal dpm output, enhanced print_r...). No need to add exposed_filters, the filter exist and it does not add anything to the debug. Tks